# Проблема с удаленным коннектом к репозиторию Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

Настраиваю сервер gitlab (удаленный), и возникла проблема
вообщем все сервисы поднял, вижу веб-морду, создаю что угодно.
Пытаюсь git clone к любой репе (удаленно) говорит:

http://mysite.com/myuser/project.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?

пробую делать тоже самое но локально на сервере тоесть через localhost и при этом указываю порт 8080 все ок, пример: 
http://localhost:8080/myuser/project.git - все отлично клонится

Делаю http://localhost/myuser/project.git' 
Говорит not found

Делаю на сервере не удаленно 
http://mysite.com/myuser/project.git
Ответ 
http://mysite.com/myuser/project.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?

Порты прописаны и фаер не блокирует, когда отключаю iptables ничего не меняется
ОС - CentOS
Если нужны конфиги, говорите какие прикреплю
Помогите, мучаюсь уже  неделю

Answer (score 3):

АЛЛИЛУЙЯ!!!!
Виновник всего был никто иной как selinux, достаточно было его отключить
Но сразу не заработало, нужно было еще перегрузить сервак :) И вот он долгожданный пуш и клон :) 
Всем спасибо!

Comment: Я самый счастливый человек